# About component "Note" : how should I use the "Raise" and "Lower" options

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using Pentaho DI ETL from a few weeks ago, and as in Talend DI ETL, there is the possibility to use a component "Note".
This is quite useful to distinguish the main features of a job, and bring more informations at the first overview when opening it.

### MY PROBLEM :

When using a note on the canvas, right-clicking on the component opens a context menu. My problem is that I am unable to use the "Raise" and "Lower" options. May someone has an idea about how those options work ?

[Screen of the context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh66a.png)

Thanks in advance,

Kapusch

### REFERENCES :

[PDI Documentation link](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0L0/0Y0/030/0A0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature enables to raise a Note over an another Note. Here is an example :

[image: Screenshot to show how to use Notes]

Hence, it is not possible to cover other components with a Note.